# How can I log source IP address information on calls to Office365

Tags: office365, ip-address, onedrive

We are a large organization moving to Office365.  Our cybersecurity policies require us to use SNAT (Source Network Address Translation) on outbound traffic to SaaS providers.  As a result of using SNAT, all entries in Microsoft's Unified Audit Log appear as coming from the same source IP address.

The problem that we need a solution for that our corporate governance has a requirement for us to support nonrepudiation and, therefore, we must log both the user identity and discrete IP address on file transactions.  Currently, we use Varonis to support this requirement internally.  Unfortunately, this requirement is blocking our deployment of OneDrive for Business as the Microsoft logs are insufficient.

As removing the SNAT is not an option, we have tried to get creative with means to capture the internal IP address and destination URL of traffic to Office365.  Logging from the router provided the IP address but does not include the URL of the destination (only the destination IP address).

Would appreciate any and all perspective.

Comment: Are you using Varonis to log file transactions on OneDrive using DatAdvantage for Office 365? I believe those logs will contain the user ID and IP address for all OneDrive events.